# Is this dryer vent installed correctly?

Tags: dryer, gas, vent, ducts, hood

Should I add those vent straps? It seems pretty sturdy, but I want to be certain. Is it even in a good location on the wall? Everyone I spoke with said it looks fine, but still a little strange to me because of where it is on the wall. It looks good on the outside though.

[image: Vent 1]
[image: Vent 2]
[image: Vent 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vent straps are normally use when flex duct is connected to rigid duct so you're fine. There shouldn't be sheet metal screws used where the rigid is connected to the rigid. The seams are taped so that's good too.

Comment: "There should be sheet metal screws used there the rigid is connected to the rigid."?? I've never heard of that recommendation for dryer ducts since they would be practically lint magnets and a fire hazard.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Thanks.  Corrected typo.